# Move files in the folder that has in its name the same compound word present in the file

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 folders called into a directory

```
Caccia
Caccia Magazine
```

In the same directory where the two folders are present I have some files like

```
Caccia.pdf
Caccia 2.pdf
Caccia Magazine aprile.pdf
Caccia Magazine gennaio.pdf
```

I want to move files into their folders in this way

```
Caccia
|
|------- Caccia.pdf
|------- Caccia 2.pdf

Caccia Magazine
|
|------ Caccia Magazine aprile.pdf
|------ Caccia Magazine gennaio.pdf
```

I use this script but it moves incorrectly because it moves (for example) `Caccia Magazine aprile.pdf` file into `Caccia` folder.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd %1
for /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%a in (`dir /b /a:-d`) do (
    set "_file=%%a"
    for /D %%b in (*) do (
        if NOT "x!_file:%%b=!" == "x!_file!" (
            move "%%a" "%%b"
        )
    )
)
popd
```

Comment: where to move "caccia maga-maga.pdf" ? in "caccia" or "caccia Magazine" ?

Comment: Using my script  will be moved to in *caccia*. But my script is not good because if you have two files called *caccia maga one.pdf* , *caccia maga two.pdf* and two folders called **caccia** and **caccia maga** both files are moved in `caccia` but I want that *caccia maga* be moved into the folder `caccia maga` **and not** in `caccia`

Comment: let's suppose that you don't have "caccia maga" as folder but only the two you have in the example. Where would you like "caccia maga.pdf" to put?. I ask you this question to understand how to find the solution when there is no exact folder but only part of the name is included.

Comment: @Einstein1969 Do you are asking, for example, what should happen if I only had *caccia maga one.pdf* , *caccia maga two.pdf* and only a folder called `caccia` **but not** `caccia maga` folder? I would like that for the **2+** *caccia maga* files a folder called 'caccia maga' was created and that both files were moved into it. I wrote **2+** because this moving only needs to happen if exists files that share the same compound word in their name.

Comment: Ok, this last information is important but I wanted to know if you have two forlder "caccia" and "caccia Magazine" and only one file "caccia maga.pdf". Where he needs to go? in "caccia" or "caccia magazine"? It is necessary to know this case because it is not clear how to choose the destination of the files.

Comment: @Einstein1969 yes, it's like you say except one detail. I have two folders: `caccia` **and** `caccia magazine`. But I need to have at least **two** files that share at least *one same* word in their name: *caccia.pdf* and *caccia magazine.pdf*. Caccia.pdf need to be moved into "caccia folder" while "caccia magazine.pdf" need to be moved into "caccia magazine" folder. Attention, I say *at least two files* because if I have caccia and caccia magazine folders and, for example, 3 files, caccia.pdf, caccia magazine 1.pdf, caccia magazine 2.pdf -->

Comment: -- > I want that caccia.pdf to be moved to "caccia" folder while caccia magazine 1 and caccia magazine 2 into "caccia magazine" folder. Why am I saying this? Because the other 2 files share the same compound word, they have in common "caccia magazine" in their name and for this reason must move to the "caccia magazine" folder

Comment: When you ask me if **"and only one file "caccia maga.pdf"** --> no,  there must be at least 2 files that share at least one same word ("caccia") in the name or one same compound word ("caccia magazine") therefore, we must have *caccia.pdf* **and** *caccia magazine.pdf* and for this reason caccia.pdf --> caccia folder while caccia magazine.pdf --> caccia magazine folder

Comment: The rule is this: not *"only one file"* but *"**two** files that share at least one single same word ('caccia') or at least **two** files that share at least one single same **compound word*** ('caccia magazine'). And it is for this reason that I also have 2 folders because the script has to compare the names of at least 2 files

Comment: Maybe I understood. If you have these files: "caccia.pdf", "caccia 2.pdf " "caccia magazine gen.pdf" "caccia magazine feb.pdf" "caccia magazi.pdf" "caccia magazi 1.pdf" "caccia magazi 2.pdf " and only two directories "caccia" and "caccia magazine" then he has to create a new directory "caccia magazi" and move the files. It is important to know what the file names are like. Are they always composed of words separated by a space? there are names like this: "caccia_magazine_mar.pdf" or "cacciamagazine_lug.pdf"?

Comment: @Einstein1969 Yes it's correct. Yes, only separated by a space, not by other symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the destination directories must already exist on running the batch file. For that reason I would suggest to focus on the names of the directories to decide which PDF files to move into which directory as done by this batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul') do if exist "%%I*.pdf" move /Y "%%I*.pdf" "%%I\"
endlocal
```

The command **FOR** with option `/F` starts in the background one more command process with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments. So it is executed in background on Windows installed into `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir /AD /B /O-N 2>nul
```

The command **DIR** executed by the background command process

- searches in the **current directory**
- just for directories because of option `/AD`
- and outputs just their names in bare format because of option `/B`
- sorted reverse by name because of option `/O-N`.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

Important is the sorted output of the directories by name in reverse order as that guarantees that the longer directory name `Caccia Magazine` is output by **DIR** before the shorter directory name `Caccia`. In other words on directory names starting with same string the longest directory name is always output first by **DIR** and the shortest last.

The output of command **DIR** to handle **STDOUT** of started background command process is captured by **FOR** respectively `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and is processed line by line after started `cmd.exe` closed itself after finishing execution of **DIR**.

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores empty lines which do not occur here. Non-empty lines would be split up by default into substrings using horizontal tab and normal space as string delimiters. That line splitting behavior is not wanted here as some directory names contain one or more spaces. For that reason the option `delims=` is used to specify an empty list of delimiters which disables the line splitting behavior. **FOR** would ignore next all lines which start with a semicolon. It is very unlikely that one of the directory names starts with a semicolon, but the end of line character is redefined with the option `eol=|` from `;` to a vertical bar which no directory name can contain ever as `|` is not allowed in a directory or file name. So no directory name output by **DIR** is ignored by **FOR** and each directory name output by **DIR** is assigned completely to the specified loop variable `I`.

The command **IF** checks if there is any `*.pdf` file in the **current directory** starting with the directory name assigned currently to the loop variable `I`. If this condition is true, all these PDF files are moved into the directory.

So as **DIR** outputs first `Caccia Magazine` because of option `/O-N`, the files matching the wildcard pattern `Caccia Magazine*.pdf` are moved first to directory `Caccia Magazine` which means moving `Caccia Magazine aprile.pdf` and `Caccia Magazine gennaio.pdf`. Next there is the directory name `Caccia` processed by **FOR** which results in an existing check for any directory entry matching the wildcard pattern `Caccia*.pdf` and as this condition is true once again, the files `Caccia.pdf` and `Caccia 2.pdf` are moved into directory `Caccia`.

Please note that PDF files are not moved for which there is not already a directory. It would be possible to insert above `endlocal` a command line like:

```
if exist *.pdf echo There are still PDF files in "%CD%".& pause
```

That command line would inform the user of the batch file that some PDF files are not moved by the batch file due to a missing directory, or a PDF file could not be moved because of being currently opened by an application or several other reasons.

Please note further that if there is a directory `Caccia`, but no directory `Caccia Magazine` in the **current directory**, that all files matching the wildcard pattern `Caccia*.pdf` are moved in this case into the directory `Caccia` including `Caccia Magazine aprile.pdf` and `Caccia Magazine gennaio.pdf`. So it is very important that directories are created wisely first before running the batch file to move the PDF files into the directories.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `setlocal /?`